# Google Books API Limit Results

Tags: php, mysql, rest, google-books

Is there any way to limit the results returned by the Google Books API?

For example the following URL:

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0751538310

Returns the following:

```
"kind": "books#volumes",
 "totalItems": 1,
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "books#volume",
   "id": "ofTsHAAACAAJ",
   "etag": "K6a+5IuCMD0",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/ofTsHAAACAAJ",
   "volumeInfo": {
    "title": "Panic",
    "authors": [
     "Jeff Abbott"
    ],
    "publisher": "Grand Central Publishing",
    "publishedDate": "2006",
    "description": "Things are going well for young film-maker Evan Casher - until he receives an urgent phonecall from his mother, summoning him home. He arrives to find her brutally murdered body on the kitchen floor and a hitman lying in wait for him. It is then he realises his whole life has been a lie. His parents are not who he thought they were, his girlfriend is not who he thought she was, his entire existence an ingeniously constructed sham. And now that he knows it, he is in terrible danger. So he is catapulted into a violent world of mercenaries, spies and terrorists. Pursued by a ruthless band of killers who will stop at nothing to keep old secrets buried, Evan's only hope for survival is to discover the truth behind his past. An absolute page-turner, Panic has been acclaimed as one of the most exciting thrillers of recent years.",
    "industryIdentifiers": [
     {
      "type": "ISBN_10",
      "identifier": "0751538310"
     },
     {
      "type": "ISBN_13",
      "identifier": "9780751538311"
     }
    ],
    "readingModes": {
     "text": false,
     "image": false
    },
    "pageCount": 408,
    "printType": "BOOK",
    "categories": [
     "Austin (Tex.)"
    ],
    "maturityRating": "NOT_MATURE",
    "allowAnonLogging": false,
    "contentVersion": "preview-1.0.0",
    "imageLinks": {
     "smallThumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=ofTsHAAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&source=gbs_api",
     "thumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=ofTsHAAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api"
    },
    "language": "en",
    "previewLink": "http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ofTsHAAACAAJ&dq=isbn:0751538310&hl=&cd=1&source=gbs_api",
    "infoLink": "http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ofTsHAAACAAJ&dq=isbn:0751538310&hl=&source=gbs_api",
    "canonicalVolumeLink": "https://books.google.com/books/about/Panic.html?hl=&id=ofTsHAAACAAJ"
   },
   "saleInfo": {
    "country": "GB",
    "saleability": "NOT_FOR_SALE",
    "isEbook": false
   },
   "accessInfo": {
    "country": "GB",
    "viewability": "NO_PAGES",
    "embeddable": false,
    "publicDomain": false,
    "textToSpeechPermission": "ALLOWED",
    "epub": {
     "isAvailable": false
    },
    "pdf": {
     "isAvailable": false
    },
    "webReaderLink": "http://books.google.co.uk/books/reader?id=ofTsHAAACAAJ&hl=&printsec=frontcover&output=reader&source=gbs_api",
    "accessViewStatus": "NONE",
    "quoteSharingAllowed": false
   },
   "searchInfo": {
    "textSnippet": "An absolute page-turner, Panic has been acclaimed as one of the most exciting thrillers of recent years."
   }
  }
 ]
```

Is there any way I can return **only** the *title* and *description*? I think it may improve performance of my web application.

I have looked at the [partial response](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/performance#partial-response) but it doesn't seem to work.

I **am** including my API key in the URL query parameter.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added the params according to the partial response documentation.

See the params in following link:

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0751538310&fields=items(volumeInfo/description,volumeInfo/title)

It will return:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "volumeInfo": {
    "title": "Panic",
    "description": "Things are going well for young film-maker Evan Casher - until he receives an urgent phonecall from his mother, summoning him home. He arrives to find her brutally murdered body on the kitchen floor and a hitman lying in wait for him. It is then he realises his whole life has been a lie. His parents are not who he thought they were, his girlfriend is not who he thought she was, his entire existence an ingeniously constructed sham. And now that he knows it, he is in terrible danger. So he is catapulted into a violent world of mercenaries, spies and terrorists. Pursued by a ruthless band of killers who will stop at nothing to keep old secrets buried, Evan's only hope for survival is to discover the truth behind his past. An absolute page-turner, Panic has been acclaimed as one of the most exciting thrillers of recent years."
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

maxResults

include this in your query.  5 is just an integer.
&maxResults=5

Google will help you create your API with this website API called try it.
https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/reference/volumes/list?apix=true#try-it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its too late to respond but you need to activate the API before accessing it. When you try to access it says to activate it from console with some project id. Just copy that url and it takes you straight to your dashboard where you can find your activation button post which you can access the partial response with desired attributes.